# Send view field in URL - Drupal

Tags: views, nodes, forms, redirection

I have a search page created with embedded filters in Drupal 8 View. In the list of fields I have a fields - [Field_program_id]. I also have a button 'Learn more' when clicking this button I want to pass the [field_program_id] and show the details of the Programs in that page. Not sure where to start. Any guidance?!

My view looks as below:

[image]

The '968' is the Program ID. Upon clicking the learn more, I want my url to be https://myproj/search?nodeid=[field_program_id]

and in this page I want to show the details again. Any help?!

Answer (score 1):

In replacement to your "Learn more" add "Custom text" field after "Field_program_id" in your views. In "Text" add "a" tag like

```
<a href="/search?nodeid={{field_program_id}}" class="button">Learn more</a>
```

Take a look in "Replacement patterns" for available fields. Read description there too for a guidance.

(this is in Drupal 8)

It is the almost the same in Drupal 7, just with [] instead {{}}. Class for "button" depends of the theme.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the field is not pulling the corresponding program ID. I am trying to use a PHP file to query the node ID from the database using the Program ID and link it with the button